# USB LAN adapter MAC/physical address

Tags: usb, lan

Does the MAC or physical address of a [USB LAN Adapter](http://www.trendygadget.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Logitec_Wireless_LANUSB_Ada.jpg) change when it is plugged into different machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. The MAC address is stored in ROM on the adapter.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address):

> MAC addresses are most often assigned by the manufacturer of a network interface card (NIC) and are stored in its hardware, the card's read-only memory, or some other firmware mechanism.

Some NIC drivers allow you to specify the MAC address (for example, if you want to clone a MAC previously registered for something like with an ISP). But this will not happen automatically. Unless you change it, the MAC will be same for any NIC, regardless of which machine it is installed in / connected to.